# Is it possible to capture GET? Method Data from a URL in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formulas

I have two Google Sheets (sheetA and sheetB) and I'd like to know if it is possible to use the following hyperlink on a cell in sheetA to capture "Ford" in a cell in sheetB.

`=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KmT653Ec0xREBw7AQlhG2jLWuPdVSqnp0nuLtgwrnI0/edit#gid=990300781?make=Ford","Ford")`

If it isn't possible using the GET Method to append the hyperlink in sheetA, do you know of another way to pass info via a hyperlink to a cell in a google sheets?

Thanks for your insight and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The `hyperlink` formula only inserts a hyperlink to be clicked by a user, it doesn't send any HTTP requests.

On the other hand, `importXML`, `importHTML`, `importFeed`,  and `importData` functions do fetch certain kinds of data (XML/HTML, HTML tables/lists, RSS/Atom, and CSV, respectively).

But apparently, your goal is to fetch data from another Google spreadsheet. The primary tool for that is `importrange`, which does not perform GET requests but directly gets the requested data from another spreadsheet with a given key or URL.